# Error securing application with users\roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

Trying to use security features and create Forms Authentication in my MVC3 application I Used Project-ASP.Net Configuration which opened ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tool.
I went to Security-Roles Management, added  a role and tried to manage users attached to it. When try to check a box to attach user
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJV74.png

I've got an error.

```
An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: The user 'user' was not found. at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.CallWebAdminHelperMethod(Boolean isMembership, String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes) at ASP.security_roles_managesinglerole_aspx.EnabledChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

May be it is smth wrong in Web.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreDB"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=my-pc;Initial Catalog=MusicStoreDB;User Id=usr;Password=1;" />
    <add name="SecDB"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=my-pc;Initial Catalog=SecDB;User Id=usr;Password=1;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="adm" />
      <allow roles="adm" />
    </authorization>
    <globalization culture="en-US" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SecDB"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="SecDB" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
          <providers>
              <add connectionStringName="SecDB" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider"
                  type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" />
          </providers>
      </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

help please

Comment: FIXED.

must use

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
          <providers>
            <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
            <add connectionStringName="SecureDB" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED.

must use

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
        <add connectionStringName="SecureDB" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Thanks!